# Scala Setting Specific Member Variables to Null

Tags: scala, oop, null

I have a class similar to the following:

```
class Cat(
   val whiskers: Vector[Whiskers],
   val tail: hasTail,
   val ears: hasEars)
```

I also have a function which initializes these values based on the contents of a file as so:

```
val whiskers = initWhiskers()
val cat = new Cat(whiskers = whiskers, tail = initTail(), ears = initEars())
```

My question is: in some cases, there exist cats with no tails or ears.  How do I account for this case by allowing for some of my cat objects to be without ears, and others to be with them?

To clarify:

```
val cat = new Cat(whiskers = whiskers, tail = null, ears = null)
val cat = new Cat(whiskers = whiskers, tail = initTail(), ears = null)
val cat = new Cat(whiskers = whiskers, tail = initTail(), ears = initEars())
```

I want all three of the above possibilities to be options.  It would all be dependent on whether the file which I'm parsing has ears, or tails, etc.

What I've tried:

Setting values to null (which was terribly unsuccessful).
Making all member variables options (which seemed like a long-winded way of getting null values again).

Any other *Options*?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have to return `null` rather than natural representation of the missing optional value `scala.None` (instance of `scala.Option`)?

Comment: Are you suggesting, roughly:  val cat = new Cat(whiskers = match { case Some(whiskers.exists()) => whiskers case None => None?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Scala, we use Option monad to wrap things which can be null.

```
class Cat(
  val whiskers: Vector[Whiskers],
  val tail: Option[hasTail],
  val ears: Option[hasEars]
)

val cat1 = new Cat(whiskers = whiskers, tail = None, ears = None)

val cat2 = new Cat(whiskers = whiskers, tail = Option(initTail()), ears = Option(initEars() )
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize you could wrap "Option" around a value to which you're setting a variable.  Would this mean that in the case initTail() doesn't initialize anything, tail would be equal to "None", else it would equal a value?

Comment: No... Wrapping a value of type `A` with `Option` gives you a value of type `Option[A]` so... if you wrap a value of type `Int` you will get `Option[Int]` but if you wrap a `None`... you will get `Option[None.type]`. For the given answer to work your `initTail()` must return a value of type `hasTail`.